# symfony2 all of a sudden broken?

Tags: php, symfony

As much as I love Symfony2, this ain't the first time I come back after not developing for a week, and there is a weird error message...

> Warning: Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer in /var/www/my_app/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php line 153

I certainly didn't touch that file... Tried googling it but only found some answers where people had used cache:clear command, or installed vendors, or moved entities. As I said, I haven't done anything... I changed the directory name where symfony2 is located, but that shouldn't affect it... Anyways I changed it back later and still same issue. Cache cleared (manually, deleted folders cache and logs) and apache2 restarted...

Anyone run into the same problem before?

Comment: However, you are not the first! Google returned something very close! See..[here](https://github.com/ahilles107/symfony-facebook/issues/2)

Comment: OK, I had tried clearing the cache (by manually deleting dir cache and logs) but apparently the command cache:clear removes additional information, because that actually worked, thanks. First time I needed to run that command after developing with symfony for a couple of months. I guess it stores absolute paths in some other file then, a file that isn't stored in cache or logs directories.

Comment: Stop the server! Go to the app/cache dir and delete everything manually! Then restart your server

Comment: Sometimes when that wild error appears.. just press cntr+f5; if it persists then clear all the cache via console.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Solution is to run the cache:clear command

```
cd symfony/app
php console cache:clear
```

and not just manually delete the folders app/cache and app/logs

Comment: Sometimes I noticed thar the cache:clear command throws the same error, so if that happens you shoud manually delete de contents of app/cache/*
And better clear the cache with the --no-warmup option

Answer (score 12):

I had this same problem, and clearing the cache was only a temporary fix. The problem was that there were two instance of Symfony that had conflicting sessions. The way I fixed it was to give each instance of Symfony their own session name in the config.yml

```
framework:
    session:
        name: "NewSessionName"
```

Comment: I was wondering why my different projects where randomly throwing errors and logging out. This did the trick for me !

Comment: I think this solution is the most effective one. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Quickiest solution for me was**

- Open up the DevTools (Chrome/FF)(Win=>F12, Mac=>CMD+Shift+i) and Go to
- Resources-> Cookies -> Domain/Host
- Delete PHPSESSID and the other Stuff / All.

Should work again!

[image: Devtools Resources-Cookies]

Comment: This worked for me :) i had 2 bundles that were not completely decoupled so I decided to merge them into one AppBundle. Session was still set.. so stupid.

Answer (score 3):

`app/console cache:clear was not working in my case and returned just the error

solution:
 delete content of cache manually

```
rm -r app/cache/dev/
```